# Why does the last list item behave differently in customized list?

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of customizing a timeline widget from [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview) which is built as an unordered list like so:

```
<ul class="timeline">

   <!-- timeline time label -->
   <li class="time-label">
      <span class="bg-red">
         10 Feb. 2014
      </span>
   </li>
   <!-- /.timeline-label -->
   <!-- timeline item -->
   <li>
      <!-- timeline icon -->
      <i class="fa fa-envelope bg-blue"></i>
      <div class="timeline-item">
         <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 12:05</span>

         <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#">Support Team</a> ...
         </h3>

         <div class="timeline-body">
            ...
            Content goes here
         </div>

         <div class="timeline-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">...</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <!-- END timeline item -->

</ul>
```

For my purposes, however, it would be great if I could have multiple `<ul></ul>`, one for each date. If I do that, the result looks like this:

[image: Gap between <ul> elements]

That is, there is a gap where I'd like the vertical line to continue down.

The CSS is as follows:

```
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.timeline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 4px;
  background: #ddd;
  left: 31px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.timeline > li {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.timeline > li:after {
  clear: both;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-item {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #444;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-item > .time {
  color: #999;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-item > .timeline-header {
  margin: 0;
  color: #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-item > .timeline-header > a {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-item > .timeline-body,
.timeline > li > .timeline-item > .timeline-footer {
  padding: 10px;
}
.timeline > li > .fa,
.timeline > li > .glyphicon,
.timeline > li > .ion {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #666;
  background: #d2d6de;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 18px;
  top: 0;
}
.timeline > .time-label > span {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.timeline-inverse > li > .timeline-item {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.timeline-inverse > li > .timeline-item > .timeline-header {
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
}
```

It looks (to me anyway) as if the `margin-bottom` of the last `<li>` doesn't get the `::before` style of the parent `<ul>` applied, whereas the preceding `<li>`'s do.

I can hack my way around that by introducing an additional `<li>` with an `.empty` class

```
         ...
         <div class="timeline-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">...</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <!-- END timeline item -->
   <li class="empty"></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
.timeline {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
.timeline li.empty {
   line-height: 0;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

While this works, it's still a hack so the question is, how can I do this in a cleaner way?

EDIT: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hn9o03m/).
EDIT 2: Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hn9o03m/1/) to get my point across

Comment: Could you replicate similar demo here on **Snippet** or at **[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)**?

Comment: use  `:last-child` to the `ul` `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` to 0 in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to remove the bottom margin:

```
.timeline > li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

To fix the spacing issue caused by zeroing the margin on the `last-child` list-item, add this:

```
.timeline > li:last-child .timeline-footer {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite. This also removes the vertical space, see `jsfiddle` in my updated question.

Comment: If you add a background color (like orange) to `.timeline > .time-label > span`, you'll see that there actually is no gap anymore. It just appears that way because of the white background on the `<span>`.

Comment: Yes, but there should be some space between the last `li` from the preceeding group and the first `li` from the next group, with a vertical line in that amount of space.

Comment: Yeah that works and at least spares me the additional `li`, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, @Aredhel.